# Moving a gameObject with Animation outside update function

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I checked how to move a `gameObject` with animation within the `Update()` function so you can use `Time.deltaTime` but I am trying to move the `gameObject` outside this function, and I also want to move the `gameObject` constantly (Travel on screen randomly). My current code without animation is:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ObjectMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    float x1, x2;
    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("move", 0f, 1f);
    }
    void move()
    {
        x1 = gameObject.transform.position.x;
        gameObject.transform.position += new Vector3(Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.1f), Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.1f), 0);
        x2 = gameObject.transform.position.x;
        if (x2 < x1)
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
        else
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
    }
    void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

What is a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) to help you.

```
Vector3 a, b;
float deltaTime = 1f/30f;
float currentTime;

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("UpdateDestiny", 0f, 1f);
    InvokeRepeating("Move", 0f, deltaTime);
}

void Move()
{
    currentTime += deltaTime;
    gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(a, b, currentTime);
}

void UpdateDestiny()
{
    currentTime = 0.0f;
    float x1, x2;
    a = gameObject.transform.position;
    x1 = a.x;
    b = gameObject.transform.position + new Vector3(Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.1f), Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.1f), 0);
    x2 = b.x;
    if (x2 < x1)
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
    else
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
}
```

Comment: You can't add a float to Vector3, line  b = gameObject.transform.position.x + new Vector3(Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.1f), Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.1f), 0);

Comment: I assume you meant without position.x ?

Comment: Okay so I got your code to work, I removed the position.x as it gave me an error, switched the order of commands inside the Start() function ( if you call move before updatedestiny then vectors a,b are empty and every gameobject will start from (0,0,0)) .. thanks :)

Comment: Yes, you can edit my post with your final code. Unfortunately I couldn't test this code.